# Python + venv = ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, windows-10, pip, idle, venv

`Win 10`, `python 3.10.5`, интерпретатор `IDLE`.
Создал вирт. окружение `venv`, активировал, установил все пакеты какие нужны,
проверил `pip list` - всё стоит.
Завожу проект - `ModuleNotFoundError:...` по всем поставленным пакетам.
`IDLE` закрыл\открыл, вирт. среду деактивировал\обратно активировал, не помогает.
`os.getcwd()` - возвращает правильную (которая нужна) папку.

Что это может быть?

Comment: попробуйте импортировать в интерпретаторе напрямую. То есть активировали `venv` в cmd, убедились, что появилось название в скобках перед путем, следом заходите в `py` и пишите строку импорта. Если не импортируется, проверяете через `pip freeze` установленные пакеты

Comment: Напрямую в cmd захожу в python, импорты работают

Comment: pip freeze показывает те же версии что и pip list

Comment: Что означает "Завожу проект"?

Comment: run или f5 - какие тут могут варианты?...

Comment: очевидно, проблема с IDLE, я к сожалению с ней не работаю. VSCode

Comment: @Garp варианты: завожу как домашнее животное (создаю проект), завожу как автомобиль (запускаю проект). Пишите так, чтобы вас понимали.

Comment: Встречное предложение - не душните.

Comment: @Garp в ваших интересах писать вопросы так, чтобы вас правильно поняли - если поймут неправильно, то вы или не получите ответ, или получите неправильный ответ. То что вам кажется душнотой - это наводящие вопросы для прояснения смысла вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказалось в `IDLE`, его надо заводить специальным образом из консоли управления (например из cmd): `python -m idlelib.idle`.